# Optimal way to select from multiple tables

Tags: abap, opensql, s4hana

I want to report from a selection on multiple tables with filters to apply.
Nothing new, but I'm wondering what is the best possible implementation (considering I'm using an S/4HANA system).

## Specification

1. *Data*
   For example, we want to retrieve the data from the tables:

   - `EKKO` order header
   - `EKPO` order item
   - `EKKN` order item assignment
   - `EKBE` order item historic

   Tables have the following relationships :

   - `EKKO` 1 - n `EKPO`
   - `EKPO` 1 - n `EKKN`
   - `EKPO` 1 - n `EKBE`
2. *Filters*

   - We would like at least one element of each table to be present (INNER JOIN), if the header does not have an item we do not upload the header data, if the item has no allocation we do not upload the data of the post, etc.
   - We would apply filters to several table areas, for example

     - `EKPO-WERKS` plant
     - etc...

## Implementation

1. *Select with join*

The first solution would be to make a selection on all the tables with joins and then disassemble them after with `LOOP AT ... GROUP BY...` then `LOOP AT GROUP`.

But already there I'm asking myself questions !
In what order should the data be selected ?  `EKKO`->`EKPO`->etc. or `EKPO`->`EKKO` etc.

2. *Multiple Select*

Select headers then the items according to the headers then the assignment according to the items etc.

The advantage is that it is more readable (not sure) and we have less redundant data, on the other hand we must apply certain filters
post selection in ABAP.

3. *???*

Another solution ?

## Conclusion

So I'm a little lost and I would like to have your opinion.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't decide the `SELECT` order, whatever you indicate `EKKO` or `EKPO` first, it's ignored, it's the database optimizer which decides. The current trend is to always use join first, and think to other solution only if there are some performance issues.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification and these tips

Comment: 3. Search for a CDS view entity that already contains all the fields you need

Comment: Thanks Jonas , i will use standard public CDS and create speécifique CDS to request my data

Comment: From my point of view the question have not been answered and this is: Which is the Best Practice 1st to have 1 query with multiple joins (at what level depth 2, 3 or more joins), 2nd to use multiple queries with FAE or 3rd Loops with selects and checks (sth that I hate). So which is the BEST PRACTICE.